# How to pass $\int_{0}^{\min(x,y)}f(x,u)f(y,u)\mathrm du$ to $\int_{0}^{y}f(y,u)\mathrm du\int_{0}^{x}f(x,u)\mathrm du$?

Tags: integration

Say I have an integral of this form:
$$\int_{0}^{\min(x,y)}f(x,u)f(y,u)\mathrm du$$
and I want to get it in this form: $$\int_{0}^{y}f(y,u)\mathrm du\int_{0}^{x}f(x,u)\mathrm du$$ Does anyone know of any practical way to do that?

Obviously I am not above multiplying and adding constants or variables that can eventually be taken out of the integral or anything like that, I just need a representation that splits the first function into two identical functions somehow. If anyone can nudge me in the right direction or could recommend a book that might it would be greatly appreciated. The function $f$ is not linear.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to write the integral of the product of functions as a product of the integral of each one.